# How to bind and unbind an event listener once executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind and unbind an event listener to only the one that has been clicked…

- User Clicks Div
- Once div is clicked… it is then binded to an event listener
- Code is executed
- At the end of code… div is then unbinded from the event listener

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clickable:not(.clicked)', function(event) {
var $this = $(this);

$this.addClass('clicked');
  
if ($this.hasClass($this.data('add-class'))) {
  $this.removeClass($this.data('add-class'));
}
else {
  $this.addClass($this.data('add-class'));
} 
 
$this.removeClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
.clickable {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #edf0f6;
margin: 10px;
transition: .5s;
float: left;
border: 1px solid transparent;}

.clickable:hover {
border: 1px solid #10cffc;
box-shadow: 0 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);}

.click1 {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.click2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg); /* Standard syntax */
    transform: rotateZ(90deg); /* Standard syntax */
}

.click3 {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-add-class="click1" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click2" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click3" class="clickable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class on clicked element and filter depending it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable:not(.clicked)', function(event) {
  $(this).addClass('clicked'); 
  //code to execute at most once for each elements in matched set
});
```

Comment: So once binded… there is no unbinding

Comment: @MonwellPartee There is but what exactly is your expected behaviour? Could you be more specific? Because in your code, you are binding click event to `document` level so i'm really not sure to understand what is your expected behaviour

Comment: I have a page… nothing is binded

Comment: Only when .clickable is clicked… it is binded to an event listener

Comment: Code is executed

Comment: Then the code… unbinds the .clickable that was clicked

Comment: Process begins again

Comment: I have a page… nothing is binded…

Comment: @MonwellPartee I see your other comments: `I could have 3 billion divs`. So ya go with delegating event to `document` level and use the logic as in my answer. Don't be afraid, here you are just binding only one click event that can handle as many as elements as you get. This is better than binding a click event for each element (3 billions...). The thing that makes your logic quite hard to understand is that you seem to want to toggle class relevant to `$this.data('add-class')` on each click, so in this case, you could set other proper logic inside a `if{}` block

Comment: I just did… but now… you cant remove the data-add-class

Comment: So its irreversible

Comment: @MonwellPartee Ok so in your code, which part of logic should be executed only once per click? Can you give an example?

Comment: check the updated code to post… can I have 15 trillion divs now without crashing computer?

Comment: @MonwellPartee But here, you aren't 'unbinding' click event. In that case, your former code was better. Again, by delegating event to `document` level, you are just binding one event, not 15 trillion... As i understand your former question, you want something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/kmpdmfo7/. And regarding the fact you can get so many elements, it won't be the event binding would could make your browser crash but the fact the browser couldn't render so many element (even in theory it could without so much problem)

Comment: There will be 15 trillion .clickables… if all 15 trillion goes through the jquery and add 15 trillion different addClass… I don't want to clutter the memory if all 15 trillion was clicked… but I want them all to have the ability to addClass-removeClass… toggle custom class

Comment: Only one div will be in the memory at a time… forever… no matter how many gets clicked… there will only be one in memory at a time… And it has to be able to remove the class… just as well as adding it.

Comment: @MonwellPartee Sorry but i don't understand what you mean by: `Only one div will be in the memory at a time… forever… no matter how many gets clicked… there will only be one in memory at a time…`. I guess you have better to test your code and if you have any issue with it, then repost a new question with minimalistic sample to replicate your issue

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `off` to unbind the event as follows, you don't need to use event delegation here since these are static elements in the html so you can select the elements by class selectors directly rather than the being obtained through delegation after document click event:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass($this.data('add-class'))) {
      $this.removeClass($this.data('add-class'));
    }
    else {
      $this.addClass($this.data('add-class'));
    } 

    $this.off('click'); // unbind me from next click 
});
```

Once the event is applied through delegation, then specific unbinding of the children is not possible, in that case, you can use @A.Wolff's solution.

Comment: So with .off() I could have 3 billion divs that goes through this code. And it will not harm computer performance… nor crash or anything… correct?

Comment: this unbind click event bound to element but click event is bound to `document`, so it doesn't work

Comment: How would I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jQuery, why not using .one() method?
http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.clickable').removeClass('add-class');
  $this.addClass('add-class');
  $this.off('click');
});
```

```css
.clickable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #edf0f6;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.clickable:hover {
  border: 1px solid #10cffc;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.click1 {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.click2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg); /* Standard syntax */
  transform: rotateZ(90deg); /* Standard syntax */
}

.click3 {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-add-class="click1" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click2" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click3" class="clickable"></div>
```